# Медиаконвертер с коммутатором

Tags: сеть

Добрый вечер.
 Не подскажете, есть ли медиаконвертер с коммутатором на 9/10/16/24/32 порта с поддержкой Gigabit Ethernet на выходе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Называется "коммутатор с SFP-портом". В SFP - порт можно вставить любой трансивер, в том числе и оптический.